# Logic of difference between freq = '1H' and freq = '60T' in pd.period_range

Tags: pandas, time-series

I am trying to understand the difference between:

```
rng = pd.period_range('2016-01-01 12:15', freq = '60T', periods = 10)
rng
```

which produces

```
PeriodIndex(['2016-01-01 12:15', '2016-01-01 13:15', '2016-01-01 14:15',
             '2016-01-01 15:15', '2016-01-01 16:15', '2016-01-01 17:15',
             '2016-01-01 18:15', '2016-01-01 19:15', '2016-01-01 20:15',
             '2016-01-01 21:15'],
            dtype='int64', freq='60T')
```

and

```
rng = pd.period_range('2016-01-01 12:15', freq = '1H', periods = 10)
rng
```

which produces

```
PeriodIndex(['2016-01-01 12:00', '2016-01-01 13:00', '2016-01-01 14:00',
             '2016-01-01 15:00', '2016-01-01 16:00', '2016-01-01 17:00',
             '2016-01-01 18:00', '2016-01-01 19:00', '2016-01-01 20:00',
             '2016-01-01 21:00'],
            dtype='int64', freq='H')
```

Is this a consistent difference with the pandas time series functionality? If so, what is the rationale and where can I find this described in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems both `Period` and `PeriodIndex` are missing from the [API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/api.html) in the documentation (as of v0.18.1) — there are references to both of them in the [Time Series / Date functionality > Time Span Representation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/timeseries.html#time-span-representation) and [Internals > Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/internals.html?highlight=period#indexing) sections though. So for fun I decided to delve into the source code to figure out how they work. Here's what I discovered.

### `Period`

`Period` objects represent *regular* intervals of time. Internally they consist of

- an integer `ordinal` that encodes the starting point of the interval, and
- an object `freq` — of type some subclass of `DateOffset` — representing the duration (essentially) as a pair of an integer multiplier `n` and a string `name` encoding a basic unit of time — seconds, minutes, hours, etc. or more complicated ones such as business days or business hours (see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) what the elementary possibilities are, and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) what their aliases are; you can also [combine them](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#combining-aliases), [anchor them](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets),...)

To translate the starting point from the integer `ordinal` to something more human-readable, multiply the basic unit of time (`freq.name`) by said integer and add that to `1970-01-01 00:00:00` (at least in my system: according to [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9056), it might depend on the frequency :-S ).

```
import pandas as pd

p1 = pd.Period('1970-01-01 00:00', 'H')
print(p1.ordinal)     # => 0
print(p1.freq.n)      # => 1
print(p1.freq.name)   # => H
print(repr(p1))       # => Period('1970-01-01 00:00', 'H')

p2 = pd.Period('1970-01-01 02:00', 'H')
print(p2.ordinal)     # => 2
print(p2.freq.n)      # => 1
print(p2.freq.name)   # => H
print(repr(p2))       # => Period('1970-01-01 02:00', 'H')

p3 = pd.Period('1970-01-01 00:00', 'M')
print(p3.ordinal)     # => 0
print(p3.freq.n)      # => 1
print(p3.freq.name)   # => M
print(repr(p3))       # => Period('1970-01', 'M')

p4 = pd.Period('1970-03-01 00:00', 'M')
print(p4.ordinal)     # => 2
print(p4.freq.n)      # => 1
print(p4.freq.name)   # => M
print(repr(p4))       # => Period('1970-03', 'M')
```

Notice that the resolution is tied to `freq.name` and it is independent of `freq.n`.

```
p5 = pd.Period('1970-03-01 00:00', '6M')
print(p5.ordinal)     # => 2
print(p5.freq.n)      # => 6
print(p5.freq.name)   # => M
print(repr(p5))       # => Period('1970-03', '6M')
```

This internal representation as an integer explains why `Period`s cannot have arbitrary starting points. Creating a `Period` object with a starting point that is not *on offset* shifts the latter towards the past until the closest *on offset* timepoint.

```
p6 = pd.Period('1970-03-05 23:59', 'M')
print(p6.ordinal)     # => 3
print(p6.freq.n)      # => 1
print(p6.freq.name)   # => M
print(repr(p6))       # => Period('1970-03', 'M')
print(p4 == p6)       # => True
```

### `PeriodIndex`

`PeriodIndex`es function as arrays of `Period`s with a common `freq`. In fact, they are stored as a pair:

- an immutable ndarray of integers — the collection of `ordinal`s, if you want — and
- a `freq` object.

`pd.period_range()` returns one of these.

```
rng = pd.period_range('2016-01-01 12:00', freq='1H', periods=5)
print(type(rng))      # => <class 'pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex'>
print(rng.values)     # => [403236 403237 403238 403239 403240]
print(rng.freq.n)     # => 1
print(rng.freq.name)  # => H
```

Accessing members of a `PeriodIndex` returns `Period` objects.

```
print(type(rng[0]))   # => <class 'pandas._period.Period'>
print(repr(rng[0]))   # => Period('2016-01-01 12:00', 'H')
```

### Where is the code?

The `Period` class is defined in [pandas/src/period.pyx](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/src/period.pyx#L665) (Cython!).

`DateOffset` and its subclasses are in [pandas/tseries/offsets.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/offsets.py#L135)

`PeriodIndex` is in [pandas/tseries/period.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/period.py#L97).